# Complained MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables. One table which contains the "packages". And a pivot table containing conditional data.

The packages table has a conditional column named 'visible'.
The meaning of the integer values in the 'visible' column are:
0 = Don't show this package at all
1 = Show this package to everyone.
2 = Show the package for specified companies, or hide the package for specified companies, as set in the pivot table.

When it's 2. You can only hide the packages or show the packages for specified companies, not both.

The pivot table has a column bind to the package, the company and a conditional boolean column called 'show'.

The meaning of the boolean values in the 'show' column are:

TRUE = Show this package for the specified company
FALSE = Hide this package for the specified company

Now I want to make a query where I can fetch all these packages at once for a specified company. I tried, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: do you want the Eloquent query?

Answer (score 0):

you should provide your tables schemas and an example so i can be more precise on my answer, maybe the query should be like this:

```php
Package::where('visible', '=', '1')
         ->union
         (
                 Package::join("name_of_your_pivot",'packages.id', '=','name_of_your_pivot.package_id')
                 ->where([
                           ['name_of_your_pivot.show', '=', TRUE ],
                           ['name_of_your_pivot.company', '=', 'name_of_company'],
                           ['packages.visible', '=', 2],
                         ])
         )->get();
```